# In MVC design, should you have a controller per model or per function group?

Tags: node.js, express, model-view-controller, model, controller

For example imagine you have a `USERS` model and a `VERIFICATION TOKEN` model (the latter used for email verification of a user), you could have a controller for each model, or you could have a controller called 'registration'. The reason I suggest this is if you have a controller per model, where would the `verifyUser()` function sit, as in this function you find both a verification token and a user?

Comment: Imagine your controller as an endpoint for a functionality, you can keep the CRUD functions associated to your models outside of your routes and call what you need upon a specific feature (like verifyUser()). Then again people will have opinionated reasons for having different architectures. I just find it easier for delegation to separate endpoints (routes) from model interactions (CRUD on the models).

Comment: Okay but a verifyUser() function performs CRUD on both users and verification tokens, so one controller would become redundant if it was placed in the other. Which is why a registration controller would make more sense because it just contains functions related to the registration process, REGARDLESS of which models the process involves.

Comment: That is basically what I was saying. Routes / endpoints are controllers and should handle a functionality, not a particular model, nor model specific CRUD functions.